# How to use image src variable in Sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid

I use Sendgrid to send some templated emails from my server. I need to put an image with an avatar so I need to pass the link as a variable. 
How can I use a variable as and image url? I tried to put {{avatar}} in the image dialog but it didn't let me save

Comment: I think you'll find my answer to a similar question relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55238802/2314315

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with normal [substitution tags](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/substitution_tags.html), using whatever you want for the tag in the message, and declaring the URL in the substitution population.